# Cppcheck syntax error code smell by C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, cppcheck

New version of cppcheck found two major code smells named "*syntax error*" in following *old* lines of code:

```
System::Reflection::Assembly^ Foo(Object^ /* obj */, System::ResolveEventArgs^ args)
        {...}
```

and

```
catch (System::Exception^ /*e*/)
```

Errortext:

```
Cppcheck cannot tokenize the code correctly.
```

Any idea how to fix them? Is something wrong with the [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) syntax?

It looks like a false positive for me, as the code compiles and works for a long time.

Comment: Isn't cppcheck for C++?

Comment: The C++/CLI `Type^` syntax does not exist in C++, so this is certainly what CppCheck is confused with.

Comment: When asking questions about errors, please always include the actual errors you get, copy-pasted as text in full and complete.

Comment: @juanchopanza the code snippets are from .cpp files which are included in a C++ solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the error text to the question.

Comment: @ViktorBe No, the code shown isn't C++ code. That is also what cppcheck is telling you actually.

Comment: As others have already pointed out, Cppcheck doesn't support C++/CLI. Try to use other analyzers. For example, PVS-Studio supports the analysis of C++/CLI and C++/CX (WinRT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to fix them?

There is nothing you can do.  C++/CLI is a dialect of C++, it is not standard C++.  cppcheck works only with standard C or C++, so it will fail to understand C++/CLI code and thus give you the diagnostic you see.  You'll need to exclude the source files that use C++/CLI code from your cppcheck check to avoid these errors.